# Present View Controller After Completed Twitter Call

Tags: objective-c, ios7, twitter, modalviewcontroller, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am attempting to present a modal view after a twitter post is successfully completed; however, I cannot present my controller because the SLComposeViewController is still presenting. Is there some completion method that will call when everything is competed and the view has been dismissed?

```
SLComposeViewController* tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        UBSTwitterSuccessViewController* twitterView;
        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                twitterView = [[UBSTwitterSuccessViewController alloc]initWithNibName:XIBTWITTERSUCCESS bundle:nil];
                [self presentViewController:twitterView animated:YES completion:nil];
                break;
        }
    };
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Check out this cool thing"];
    [tweetSheet addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cad-comic.com/"]];

    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:nil];
```

warning with no view presented:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UBSTwitterSuccessViewController: 0x16569b70>  on <UINavigationController: 0x1663bd30> which is already presenting <SLComposeViewController: 0x166b1170>
```

Answer (score -1):

`SLComposeViewController` has `completionHandler` in which you assign a block to be executed when user finished or cancelled composing the post.

> completionHandler The handler to call when the user is done composing
>   a post.
>
> @property (nonatomic, copy) SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler
>   completionHandler Discussion The handler has a single parameter that
>   indicates whether the user finished or cancelled composing the post.
>   This block is not guaranteed to be called on any particular thread.
>
> Special Considerations In iOS 6 and earlier, if you set a completion
>   handler then your completion handler is responsible for dismissing the
>   SLComposeViewController using
>   dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:. In iOS 7 and later when
>   compiled with the iOS 7 or later SDK you must not dismiss the
>   SLComposeViewController in your completion handler—the system will do
>   so automatically.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SLComposeViewController/completionHandler)

Comment: I'm using completionHandler, but the issue is that the SLComposeViewController is still being presented when the completion handler runs, so presenting another view controller fails.

Comment: You have to dismiss `tweetSheet` first.
`case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                      twitterView = [[UBSTwitterSuccessViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:XIBTWITTERSUCCESS bundle:nil];
                      [self presentViewController:twitterView animated:YES completion:nil];
                  }];`

Comment: "In iOS 7 and later when compiled with the iOS 7 or later SDK you must not dismiss the SLComposeViewController in your completion handler—the system will do so automatically." I'm coding for iOS 7.